# C# Multiple inheritance replacement

Tags: c#, wpf, multiple-inheritance

I am looking or a better way to do in C# what would otherwise be a simple multiple inheritance pattern.

I have Master and Slave windows inheriting from WPF's Window class and I want them both to have another common interface/functionality.
I thought first of implementing a BaseWindow class that would inherit from Window and both Slave and Master would inherit from, 

**but due to some issues in WPF they (Master and Slave windows) have to inherit directly from Window (NOT BaseWindow)**.
So then I defined an interface like so

```
public interface MasterOrSlaveWindow
{
    View CurrentView { get; set; }
}
```

And both Master and Slave implement it:

```
public partial class SlaveWindwow : Window, MasterOrSlaveWindow
{
    protected View m_CurrentView = null;
    public View CurrentView { 
        get { return m_CurrentView; } 
        set 
        {
            if (value == null && m_CurrentView != null)
                m_CurrentView.Owner = null;

            m_CurrentView = value; 

            if (m_CurrentView != null) 
                m_CurrentView.Owner = this;
        } 
    }
}
```

It works in the case where the implementation is different, but for the case when it is the same we have code duplication:

```
public partial class MasterWindwow : Window, MasterOrSlaveWindow
{
    protected View m_CurrentView = null;
    public View CurrentView { 
        get { return m_CurrentView; } 
        set 
        {
            if (value == null && m_CurrentView != null)
                m_CurrentView.Owner = null;

            m_CurrentView = value; 

            if (m_CurrentView != null) 
                m_CurrentView.Owner = this;
        } 
    }
}
```

What's a good way to avoid code duplication in this case?

Comment: You could try to solve the "must inherit directly from window" problem.. Or, you could extract the `CurrentView` property to a separate class and have your windows passthrough to an instance of it.

Comment: Use composition instead of inheritance. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition

Comment: I find it hard to believe that they must inherit directly from Window, but I haven't done WPF for a while so can't make a valid judgment here.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this using DI-like style:

```
public interface IWindowHandler
{
    View GetCurrentView();
}

public class MasterWindowHandler : IWindowHandler
{
    public View GetCurrentView()
    {
    }
}

public class SomeOtherWindowHandler : IWindowHandler
{

    public View GetCurrentView()
    {
    }
}

// all your windows should inherit from this type
public class MyBaseWindow : Window
{

    protected IWindowHander _handler;

    public MyBaseWindow(IWindowHandler handler)
    {
        _handler = handler;
    }

    protected View m_CurrentView = null;

    public View CurrentView 
    { 
        get { return m_CurrentView; } 
        set 
        {
            // your code
        }
    } 
}

// a sample window code
public partial class MasterWindow : MyBaseWindow 
{
    public MasterWindow(IWindowHandler handler) : base(handler)
    {
    }
}
```

Of course you have to take care inside the instantiation of the window but you can easily change the implementation without touching the window itself.

```
using (var window = new MasterWindow(new MasterWindowHandler()))
{

}
```

Comment: Don't forget to make your classes implement that interface.

Comment: @DavidG Thanks I added that

Comment: Not an answer due to using BaseWindow (which I mentioned at the top of my question)

Comment: @ILIABROUDNO You don't have to inherit from BaseWindow at all. I just left the code as it was in your sample to give you a starting point. You could put everything into the interface and inherti from Window normally.